# Finding table row number in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I use following statement to find number of table rows, it works fine in Firefox & Chrome but always returns 1 in IE, what is going wrong?

```
document.getElementById('<%=tblBasket.ClientID %>').rows.length
```

Comment: I'm guessing because IE doesn't support `elem.rows` the same as the other browsers? Have you `console.log(elem.rows);` to see what you're getting?

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/csQC5/

Comment: @MichalKlouda - Hmm, works for me too with IE7/8/9 using Developer Tools and browser modes. Hmm.

Comment: Can you show us a demo of this error? Worksforme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('<%=tblBasket.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('tr').length
```

Comment: @Ali_dotNet You should try it.

Comment: @xdazz - Just wondering, Michal's fiddle demonstrates it can work; would a `thead` row possibly make this *not* work as expected?

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` should not be needed, IE supports the `rows` property. Also it returns wrong results in nested tables

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, I'm kinda wondering too. With `thead` and `tbody` rows: http://jsfiddle.net/csQC5/1/

Comment: At least it looks like it's a good idea to actually be more specific that just the table, ie, look for the `thead` instead of just the `table`.

Comment: IE supports the rows property but you take the risk of having it return wrong results NOT ONLY in nested tables. Just had an issue where it returned only the rows that had hidden <td> elements - weird. Probably because the table also had a <script> and a <style> inside, before the last <tr>. But Firefox and Chrome were handling it correctly.