# Getting table cell content in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I can get table cell contents using following statement in Firefox, but no luck in IE:

```
document.getElementById('<%=tblBasket.ClientID %>').rows[i].cells[0].innerText
```

Also I have tested innerHTML, again with no luck, I think the way I call `.rows[i].cells[0].` has a problem which gives nothing for IE, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [you get proper answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131316/error-in-finding-table-row-number-in-ie) how do deal with it. Why you ask almost same thing again? Why do you use `.rows` property if you know is not working in IE?

Comment: Accessing `table` elements in IE using DOM methods is different than other browsers.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - It's not the same question (number of rows versus accessing cells). And `.rows` does work in IE.

Comment: Of course it is not the same thing, I know they are similar, but they are not same, please help me

Comment: thanks Jared, how can I fix this problem? can I use one method for all browsers?

Comment: I'm puzzled here. `innerText` should **not** work in Firefox because it's an IE-only property, but should work in IE.

Comment: `document.getElementById('<%=tblBasket.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML` ??

Comment: Well... It's been a while since I did DOM-level table manipulation IE. I believe jQuery allows you to manipulate tables cross-browser, which is what I use just for this reason.

Comment: @JaredFarrish But Ali's not using jQuery, I fear. `innerHTML` should do the trick, but we need some more HTML/JS code to understand what's wrong.

Comment: @MaxArt - It's been a while, but `table`s in IE are treated differently than regular DOM elements (kind of like `form`s have their own methods). I'm hazy on what exactly, but I remember it being a "code twice" problem more or less. And yeah, I know jQuery wasn't mentioned. That's just what I use. `;)`

Comment: I think what Peter said has done the trick! thanks everybody, it works in both browsers

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - Peter, see the OPs comment above.

Comment: @JaredFarrish he should take lesson from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131316/error-in-finding-table-row-number-in-ie) :))

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - You still think these are identical answers? Well, to each their own.

Comment: @JaredFarrish maybe not, but answer is almost the same  :)

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - Dogs and cats are more similar than dissimilar. Still completely different animals.

Comment: @JaredFarrish you are right, i don't want to argue, i'm just saying he should take lesson that `.rows` attribute is not working

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - `.rows` is [supported by IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); read the comments under the answer on that page. The reason I notified you of the OPs comment above was in case you wanted to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var table = document.getElementById('<%=tblBasket.ClientID %>');
var rows  = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var cols  = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
var col   = cols[0];
var html  = col.innerHTML;
```

and one-liner:

```
document.getElementById('<%=tblBasket.ClientID %>').getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML
```